# Warnings after recompiling php (Unable to load dynamic library & Unable to initialize module)

Tags: warnings, php-extension, php

After recompiling php I get the following errors when I use php cli:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: imap: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20050922
PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/modules/ldap.so' - /usr/lib/php/modules/ldap.so: undefined symbol: third_arg_force_ref in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/modules/mbstring.so' - /usr/lib/php/modules/mbstring.so: undefined symbol: second_arg_force_ref in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mysql: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20050922
PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mysqli: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20050922
PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: PDO: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20050922
PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pdo_mysql: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20050922
PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pdo_sqlite: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20050922
PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/modules/mapi.so' - /usr/lib/php/modules/mapi.so: undefined symbol: fourth_arg_force_ref in Unknown on line 0
```

After some googling I found that the modules have to be updated, I tried:

```
pecl install <modulename>
```

and

```
pecl upgrade <modulename>
```

and

```
pear install -f pecl/<modulename>
```

but I got errors like:

```
configure: error: mysql_query missing!?
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/PDO_MYSQL/configure' failed
```

Or errors like:

```
make: *** [sqlite_driver.lo] 
Error 1 ERROR: `make' failed
```

Any idea how to update the modules?

If there was anything that I should have done before compiling please explain to me because I'm going to recompile php on other servers and I want to know the solution before I face the same problem again.

Thanks in advance.

PS: My OS is Linux (Redhat)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem you're having is that your php and module APIs are different, e.g.:

```
Module compiled with module API=20050922     <----- this
PHP    compiled with module API=20090626     <----- and this should match.
```

I usually install extensions by compiling them from source, which seems to work a lot more reliably.

You'll need to use [phpize](http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.phpize.php)

As an example, here's how I'd install APC:

```
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/APC-3.1.9.tgz
tar -xvzf APC-3.1.9.tgz
cd APC-3.1.9
phpize
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

This should work for all PECL extensions. Now, you also have other errors.. I would suggest going through your php.ini and disabling all extensions at first - then enable and fix one by one.

There's also an error about mysqli. If you're using php >= 5.0.0, then you'll need to re-compile php (with ./configure [....] --with-mysqli), otherwise the procedure above should work for it as well.

HTH